# Ubuntu 18.04 BCM43142A0 bluetooth problem

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth, firmware

I have a problem with Bluetooth on my Laptop. It seems to get stuck on searching for devices.

I looked through AskUbuntu already and found a few great, detailed solutions, but I don't know what firmware I need. Here are the outputs of commands I found online:

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth

[   20.793040] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   20.793074] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   20.793081] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   20.793085] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   20.793095] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.153861] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   21.154856] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   21.170837] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   21.170844] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   21.449876] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   21.449883] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   24.056776] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   24.058451] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[ 5417.077645] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 5417.077649] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 5417.077657] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 5513.623521] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 5513.623532] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 5513.623543] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 5538.321869] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 5538.323516] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[ 5734.376654] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000094ad7f77 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 5739.698606] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 5739.699750] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 5739.715784] Bluetooth: hci0: patryk-Lenovo-G50-45
[ 5739.715798] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 5739.715927] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[ 5739.715934] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
```

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see it tries to load `BCM.hcd` firmware and while I found this repository on Github: https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware I don't know which firmware I should use.

Comment: According to [linux-hardware.org][1] drivers should be present in the kernel from version 4.14 and onwards. And I believe 18.04 started with 4.14 so technically it should work. Obviously, it doesn't and your errors seem to match those described by the Github project. However, just as a test, I would try booting from a more recent release, say 19.10, with a newer kernel, just to see if any kinks might not have been ironed out.


  [1]: https://www.linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:105b-e065&page=4

Comment: Will do once I get a chance. Thanks